# What does "reputation-bibbing" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I read this sentence: "In all his writing (and, apparently, conversation) [Roy] Jenkins loved reputation-bibbing, loved all kinds of ranking, especially of politicians."

What does "reputation-bibbing" mean?

Answer (score 5):

Presumably a kind of addiction, by analogy with [wine-bibbing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wine-bibbing?s=t), to assessing and possibly messing with people’s reputations. For an excellent theatrical study of such an addiction, I recommend Richard Brinsley Sheridan’s *[The School for Scandal](https://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/nael/noa/pdf/27636_Rest_U19_Brinsley.pdf)* (1777).

Comment: The full OED definition for ***to bib*** is *To drink; keep on drinking, tipple,* and where ***bibbing*** is preceded by a noun it's often some kind of alcoholic drink (but there are plenty of instances of [***blood-bibbing***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blood-bibbing%22) in Google Books). Since the "core" meaning obviously implies "consuming with **gusto / relish**", I think we can probably assume the intended sense is that Roy Jenkins liked ***name-dropping*** (attempting to enhance one's *own* reputation by interacting with and talking about *other* "famous" people).